# Why files from static not shows on page?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I made for test such simple project in django

I've created views

from django.shortcuts import render

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'app1/home.html', {})
```

Further i've created url

```
from courseshop import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from app1 import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home')
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I add some things in settings for static

```
import os

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = []

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And i've made template home.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Мой сайт</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; " charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align="center">Привет всему миру!</h1>

        <p>Регистр (цифровая техника) — последовательное или параллельное логическое устройство, используемое для хранения n-разрядных двоичных чисел и выполнения преобразований над ними.</p>
       
        <img src="{% static '/Python/django/courseshop/app1/static/app1/images/stars.jpeg' %}"
        <hr>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my templates settings

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_
```

And i don't see image stars on my page. Why? Please, help me

Answer (score 0):

when you want to use static files in your template, you should add load static in the beggining of your template and use it like this:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'app1/images/stars.jpg' %}"
```

Comment: nothing Matin, i've tried

Comment: I see you added this path to your template : /Python/django/courseshop/  you should remove it, just you need this path app1/images/stars.jpg

Comment: now you should have a static folder in your project,inside it there is a images folder and inside images there is stars.jpg right ?

Answer (score -1):

plz add templates name in settings.py file

TEMPLATES = [
{

```
    'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
    ...
},
```

]

plz check all path

.html img path
views.py

Comment: nothing(, added

Comment: @NazimPatel, (a) "Go and watch a video" is not how we answer questions here. Please read [answer]. (b) "2 different YouTube channel videos" isn't very specific.